# Bluetooth Dongle and Macbook Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I usually work on my macbook and I can ssh to the raspberry pi for many of my tasks. However, I want to use my TV monitor which is connected to raspberry pi and have my Macbook keyboard as the input device.  I can buy a Bluetooth USB dongle, but is it possible to pair it with a macbook keyboard or a application within the computer to take input?

Comment: Not sure if you need extra notification, but two answers have just been posted...

Comment: @xxmbabanexx - thanks! I adopted a different approach for my problem. Mac keyboard + using synergy instead of a bluetooth dongle.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that only certain Bluetooth devices will work with the Raspberry Pi and you may need to install some software on the Pi itself for it to work.

This guide is quite popular and could help - http://www.ctheroux.com/2012/08/a-step-by-step-guide-to-setup-a-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site!

It turns out that there is an app on the Mac App store called [iKeyBoard](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ikeyboard/id441439411?mt=12) which will allow you to pair your MacBook keyboard with a bluetooth device.

Credits: [Apple Store Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3903767?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of purchasing a Bluetooth dongle and trying to connect with an application on my mac, I used synergy software which can help me share my mac's keyboard and mouse and control the raspberry pi output. This works good for my setup and I will be using the same instead of purchasing any additional hardware.